# How to subtract 7 days from current date with Moment.js

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, substr

I would like to subtract `7` days from current date to get formatted date `YYYY-MM-DD` using moment.js library.

I tried to do by this way:

```js
dateTo = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
dateFrom = moment(new Date() - 7).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

console.log(dateFrom);
console.log(dateTo);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.4/moment.min.js"></script>
```

But all returned values are same.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

May be:

```
dateTo = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD');
dateFrom = moment().subtract(7,'d').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

[moment#subtract](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/)

Comment: Also worth noting, `moment(new Date()) === moment()`

Comment: Awesome, but How can I get date when I pass from date like parameters(another way, current date is not today)?

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
moment().subtract(1,'w')
```

to subtract one week (7 days) from the current date.

```
NOTE:
1. w for week
2. d for days
3. M for month
4. y for year
```

Comment: Just notice that `'M'` should be used for month, `'m'` stands for minutes according to the document.
Reference: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

Comment: nice catch @TysonZ

Answer (score 6):

The date object, when casted, is in milliseconds. so:

```
dateFrom = moment(Date.now() - 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Comment: And what if i would like to pass something like dateTo - dateFrom?

Comment: [`Date.getMilliseconds()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/getMilliseconds)

Comment: This approach is not safe for dates near daylight saving time transitions.  Not all days are 24 hours in length.

Answer (score 2):

for a date picker y use

```
 first_day: moment()
    .subtract(5, "day")
    .endOf("day")
    .toDate(),
  last_day: moment()
    .endOf("day")
    .toDate(),
```

Answer (score 2):

The question is outdated so does the solution.

Using Moment v2.29 +

You can add or subtract days using following ways

```
moment().day(-7); // last Sunday (0 - 7)
moment().day(0); // this Sunday (0)
moment().day(7); // next Sunday (0 + 7)
moment().day(10); // next Wednesday (3 + 7)
moment().day(24); // 3 Wednesdays from now (3 + 7 + 7 + 7)
```

For more please refer the official documentation https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/

Answer (score 0):

**Easiest method to get last 7th day**

```
moment().subtract(7, 'days').startOf('day').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```