# Display three days before date from current moment in ember .hbs file using moment.js?

Tags: ember.js, momentjs

I have to subtract three days from the current date. I had referred few other [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888182/moment-js-how-to-substract-7-days-from-current-date) , but the solution is listed using js file.

> I should not use .js file of ember
>
> Challenge is how to do it in .hbs file ? ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Handlebar Moment](http://moment.handlebars.solidgoldpig.com/) so it's easy

```
{{moment d subtract="days" amount="3"}}
```

or

```
{{moment date=d format='YYYY-MM-DD' subtract='days' amount='3'}}
```

Give it a try