# Subtract 7 days from moment date getting Invalid Date

Tags: javascript, list.js

Trying to subtract 7 days from date using moment.js. But, invalid date in the console. I'm first consoling the date in the span element with data-date attribute then creating a new variable and assigning it the data minus 7. My end goal is to add an event handler to a button to only display dates that are within the last 7 days. Codepen: https://codepen.io/centem/pen/ExYEoLj

```js
var dataset = [
  {date: "2019-04-15T15:10:45Z", number: 76},
  {date: "2019-02-12T11:21:10Z", number: 23},
  {date: "2019-01-12T10:20:16Z", number: 14},
  {date: "2019-01-09T09:20:16Z", number: 7},
  {date: "2019-07-11T11:01:05Z", number: 101},
  {date: "2019-08-29T11:01:05Z", number: 121},
  {date: "2019-09-03T14:31:05Z", number: 130},
  {date: "2019-09-10T11:01:05Z", number: 135},
  {date: "2019-09-11T14:01:05Z", number: 140},
  {date: "2019-09-01T11:01:05Z", number: 115}
];

var options = { 
  valueNames : ['date', 'number', 'filter'] 
};
var ResultDiv = new List('ResultDiv', options);

for(let node of document.querySelectorAll('[data-date]')){
  let d = moment(new Date(node.dataset.date)).format("MMM Do YYYY hh:mm:ss");
  //node.innerText = moment(new Date(node.dataset.date)).format("MMM Do YYYY hh:mm:ss");
  node.innerText = d;
  //console.log(node.innerText);
}

//moment().subtract(7, 'days');
//var d = new Date();
//var d2 = new Date();
//var d2 = d2.setDate( d.getDate() - 10 );
//d = moment(d).format("MMM Do YYYY hh:mm:ss");
//document.write( d )
//document.write("<br>");
//d2 = moment(d2).format("MMM Do YYYY hh:mm:ss");
//document.write( d2 );

function formatDate(d) {
  return moment(d).format("MMM Do YYYY hh:mm:ss");
}
/*
function addElements() {
  let ul = document.getElementById("ul");
  
  for (let i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    let outerDateSpan = document.createElement("span");
    let innerDateSpan = document.createElement("span");
    let numberSpan = document.createElement("span");
    let d = formatDate(dataset[i].date);
    innerDateSpan.setAttribute("data-date", d);
    innerDateSpan.classList.add("date");
    innerDateSpan.innerHTML = d;
    numberSpan.classList.add("number");
    numberSpan.innerHTML = dataset[i].number;
    outerDateSpan.appendChild(innerDateSpan);
    li.appendChild(outerDateSpan);
    li.appendChild(numberSpan);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
}
*/
//addElements();

function last7() {
  for(let node of document.querySelectorAll('[data-date]')){
    console.log("***********************************");
    let d = node.innerText;
    console.log(d);
    let d2 = moment(d).subtract(7, 'days');
    console.log(d2);
    //console.log( moment(node.innerText).subtract(7, 'days') );
  }
}

last7();
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
span {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>

<div id="ResultDiv">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search"/>
  <button class="sort" data-sort="date">
    Sort by Date
  </button>
  <button class="sort" data-sort="number">
    Sort by Number
  </button>
  <button>Last 7 Days</button>
  <button>Last 30 Days</button>

    <ul class="list" id="ul">
      <li>
        <span class="date"><span data-date="2019-04-15T15:10:45Z"></span>
            </span>
        <span class="number">76</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="date"><span data-date="2019-02-12T11:21:10Z"></span></span>
        <span class="number">23</span>
      </li>
            <li>
              <span class="date"><span data-date="2019-01-12T10:20:16Z"></span></span>
        <span class="number">14</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="date"><span data-date="2019-01-09T09:20:16Z"></span></span>
        <span class="number">7</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="date"><span data-date="2019-07-11T11:01:05Z"></span></span>
        <span class="number">101</span>
      </li>
            <li>
              <span class="date"><span data-date="2019-08-29T11:01:05Z"></span></span>
        <span class="number">121</span>
      </li>
      <li>
              <span class="date"><span data-date="2019-09-03T14:31:05Z"></span></span>
        <span class="number">130</span>
      </li>
            <li>
              <span class="date"><span data-date="2019-09-10T11:01:05Z"></span></span>
        <span class="number">130</span>
      </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the subtraction that fails and not the initialisation itself - `moment(d)`?

Comment: Running the example - yeah, that's EXACTLY what that warning is about. You are feeding moment some date but without a known format to it, it doesn't necessarily know what to do with it. So, it fails. It's not the subtraction itself.

Comment: maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888182/moment-js-how-to-subtract-7-days-from-current-date
Try replacing 'days' with 'd' in subtract method

Comment: Its a negative on the 'd' Karan.

Answer (score 0):

In your function `last7()`, change

```
let d = node.innerText;
```

to

```
let d = node.getAttribute("data-date");
```

Because, innerText will give you an already formatted value which will not be recognized by moment, instead use what you already have in your data attribute.

See the working code below.

```js
var dataset = [
  {date: "2019-04-15T15:10:45Z", number: 76},
  {date: "2019-02-12T11:21:10Z", number: 23},
  {date: "2019-01-12T10:20:16Z", number: 14},
  {date: "2019-01-09T09:20:16Z", number: 7},
  {date: "2019-07-11T11:01:05Z", number: 101},
  {date: "2019-08-29T11:01:05Z", number: 121},
  {date: "2019-09-03T14:31:05Z", number: 130},
  {date: "2019-09-10T11:01:05Z", number: 135},
  {date: "2019-09-11T14:01:05Z", number: 140},
  {date: "2019-09-01T11:01:05Z", number: 115}
];

var options = { 
  valueNames : ['date', 'number', 'filter'] 
};
var ResultDiv = new List('ResultDiv', options);

for(let node of document.querySelectorAll('[data-date]')){
  let d = moment(new Date(node.dataset.date)).format("MMM Do YYYY hh:mm:ss");
  node.innerText = d;
}

function formatDate(d) {
  return moment(d).format("MMM Do YYYY hh:mm:ss");
}


function last7() {
  for(let node of document.querySelectorAll('[data-date]')){
    console.log("***********************************");
    let d = node.getAttribute("data-date");
    console.log(d);
    let d2 = moment(d).subtract(7, 'days');
    console.log("d2", d2);
    //console.log( moment(node.innerText).subtract(7, 'days') );
  }
}

last7();
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
span {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>

<div id="ResultDiv">
  <input class="search" placeholder="Search"/>
  <button class="sort" data-sort="date">
    Sort by Date
  </button>
  <button class="sort" data-sort="number">
    Sort by Number
  </button>
  <button>Last 7 Days</button>
  <button>Last 30 Days</button>

    <ul class="list" id="ul">
      <li>
        <span class="date"><span data-date="2019-04-15T15:10:45Z"></span>
            </span>
        <span class="number">76</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="date"><span data-date="2019-02-12T11:21:10Z"></span></span>
        <span class="number">23</span>
      </li>
            <li>
              <span class="date"><span data-date="2019-01-12T10:20:16Z"></span></span>
        <span class="number">14</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="date"><span data-date="2019-01-09T09:20:16Z"></span></span>
        <span class="number">7</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="date"><span data-date="2019-07-11T11:01:05Z"></span></span>
        <span class="number">101</span>
      </li>
            <li>
              <span class="date"><span data-date="2019-08-29T11:01:05Z"></span></span>
        <span class="number">121</span>
      </li>
      <li>
              <span class="date"><span data-date="2019-09-03T14:31:05Z"></span></span>
        <span class="number">130</span>
      </li>
            <li>
              <span class="date"><span data-date="2019-09-10T11:01:05Z"></span></span>
        <span class="number">130</span>
      </li>
    </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: void I'm not getting the same output even though I copied your last7 function exactly.